# redirect thumbnail to corresponding image on new html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to redirect img thumbnail to corresponding img on new html page.

For example : http://www.damondebacker.com/music.html
this page contains overview of all pictures

http://www.damondebacker.com/musicd.html
this page contains scrolldown + column with large picture

I want to know how I can link every image to the scrolldown/large picture pages so it opens on the clicked image.

I have found this so far :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      "use strict";
       $('img.musicd').click(function() {
          window.location.href = this.class +'.html' ;
      });
   });
```

Which doesn't work.. And I know I need to integrate somehow

$( ".images" ).hide();
    $( "#een" ).show();

With #een being the id of the image that opens when the musicdd page opens.

I am relatively new to javascript and I'm looking for the best possible way to explain this problem. Hope anyone can give me advice?

Comment: Provide us with your HTML, CSS and JS code

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I kept it as simple as possible. My code uses jQuery. Here you are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="thumbnails">
    <img src="one.jpg" alt="...">
    <img src="two.jpg" alt="...">
    <img src="three.jpg" alt="...">
  </div>
  <img src="" alt="..." id="main">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {                                   // I wait the DOM loading
      $("#thumbnails img").on("click", function () {  // when I click a thumbnail
        var x = $(this).attr("src");                  // I save its src attribute
        $("#main").attr("src", x);                    // and use it as the src of the #main image
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! so after you save its src attribute another page opens at that img, id="main" is another page.. Does that still work?

Comment: @Emilie not a new page: it will fill the `img` tag under the three thumbnails. You can see it in the HTML code

Comment: @Emilie Was it helpful for you?

Comment: @Emilie let me understand better. Do you want to have an array of thumbnails on which you can click and then the image would be opened in a new page?

Comment: I tried to explain it better in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988745/how-to-open-a-new-page-with-the-same-image-showing-as-you-clicked-on-using-jquer/42989001#42989001    However when I do the tutorial suggested I  it doesn't work